# Extended User Model not updating

Tags: python, django, rest

Hii I'am new to Django rest frame work and was preparing API's So this is my
models.py

```
class User(auth.models.User, auth.models.PermissionsMixin):
    def __str__(self):
    return "@{}".format(self.username)

class User_log(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(auth.models.User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='user_logs')
    fullname=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    fb_login=models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.fullname
```

serializers.py

```
class userSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    fullname = serializers.StringRelatedField(source='user_logs.fullname',read_only=False)
    fb=serializers.BooleanField(source='user_logs.fb_login')
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields=('id','username','email','fullname','fb')
        related_fields = ['user_logs']
    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        # Handle related objects
        for related_obj_name in self.Meta.related_fields:
        print('exe')
        print(instance,validated_data)
        # Validated data will show the nested structure
        data = validated_data.pop(related_obj_name)
        related_instance = getattr(instance, related_obj_name)

        # Same as default update implementation
        for attr_name, value in data.items():
            setattr(related_instance, attr_name, value)
        related_instance.save()
        return super(userSerializers,self).update(instance, validated_data)
```

viewset.py

```
class Userview(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class=userSerializers
```

Now the problem: whenever i try to update fullname column through json request
`{ "id": 2,"username": "karam","email": "karam@83ideas.com","fullname": "karm","fb": true }`
 i am getting this error `"POST /accounts/accounts/2/ HTTP/1.1" 405 41`
and as in serializers.py update method i have printed the validated data instead of this

```
karam {'username': 'karam', 'email': 'karam@83ideas.com', 'user_logs': {'fullname':'karam','fb_login': True}}
```

i am getting this

```
karam {'username': 'karam', 'email': 'karam@83ideas.com', 'user_logs': {'fb_login': True}}
```

[image]
SO any idea how to resolve it?

Comment: If you're updating existing record then why you're using POST method? 405 error saying that method (request) not allowed.

Comment: well i also used put "PUT /accounts/accounts/2/ HTTP/1.1" 400 76"

Comment: And what is the response for PUT? 400 status is about that error happened (bad request).

Comment: Method Not Allowed: /accounts/accounts/2/

Comment: Hm, are you sure this is the response for PUT request? Asking because this is the default response for 405 status, where you get 400.

Comment: But if iam updating fb_login to true or flase its working but that's not case with fullname field

Comment: Why do you inherit from `auth.models.User`? That is not an abstract model hence it means you create a one to one relationship with it. You should inherit from `auth.models.AbstractUser` and set `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'yourapp.User'` in your settings. Also to create a foreign key or any other relation to user always use `ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, .....)`

Comment: so does this thing have to do with REST API's? just asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using StringRelatedField in serializers.py use CharField.

```
class userSerializers(serializers.ModelSerializer):
fullname=serializers.CharField(source='user_logs.fullname')
fb=serializers.BooleanField(source='user_logs.fb_login')
class Meta:
    model = User
    fields=('id','username','email','fullname','fb')
    related_fields = ['user_logs']
```